# Monitoring Spring boot applications : gather service/node availability data for offline reporting

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, availability

I would like to gather and store data on the availability of the service or node. The day after I could summarize the figures, like { day-1: service = 98.5%; day-2 = 99%}.

I could get the data by calling a simple rest (ping) service (e.g. via Actuator or what). Then I would need to write a custom scheduled application calling the Actuator/ping services.

Is there a simple solution for collecting/storing the availability data? Via Spring Batch?

**UPDATE 31-05**: I read about [**Spring Boot Admin**](http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.5.0/#getting-started). Is this the right solution? See also this [introduction](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/08/spring-boot-admin-2/).

The data could be extracted and formatted in a CSV, JasperReporting, etc.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: Often. Not Always.

Comment: That was related to the question at hand... With the actuator just register an exporter (see the documentation).

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-metric-writers)? I suggest a read of that instead of trying to get answers. If your application is up, the actuator is up, if that is down, generally your app is down as well.

Comment: Is Spring Boot Admin a good choice? Anyone experience with this application in delivering availability percentage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that I can help you. I think that what you need is a way of monitoring your applications in a persistent way. You can build your own solution creating a Ping resource and scheduling a client to collect availability information from time to time. But, to no re-invent the wheel, a really suggest you use some professional tool.

I recommend that you use a Dashboard tool like Grafana to create these reports, and I suggest you try Prometheus to capture monitoring pieces of information.

I have listed some links below.

- [Actuator and Prometheus](http://blog.monkey.codes/actuator-and-prometheus/)
- [monitoring-spring-boot-applications-with-prometheus](https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2016/09/24/monitoring-spring-boot-applications-with-prometheus/)
- [Prometheus dashboard in Grafana](https://prometheus.io/docs/visualization/grafana/)